# Can't select option after deselecting it with JQuery or in UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

In a `select` tag with `multiple` attribute.

When I was using old [multi-select](https://github.com/lou/multi-select) JQuery plugin, I find out that I can't select previously deselected options. Actually, I can see that they are selected in UI that created with that plugin, but they were not selected when I submit the form.

Then, I tried to remove selection and select it again from the console without any JQuery plugin.

After deselecting the selection by removing attribute `selected` from option:

```
document.getElementById('option_1').removeAttribute('selected');
```

I was able to select that option again without any problem using JS code:

```
document.getElementById('option_1').setAttribute('selected', '');
```

But, when I tried to remove the `selected` attribute with JQuery `removeAttr` or `prop`:

```
$("#option_1").removeAttr('selected');
$("#option_1").prop('selected',false);
```

It removes the selection, but I can't select that same option again. Tried both JQuery and JS:

```
$("#option_1").attr('selected','selected');

document.getElementById('option_1').setAttribute('selected', '');
```

Again, I can't select the same option with `code` when I manually deselect option with `ctrl+(right-click to selected option)`

**1.** Why it happens?

**2.** I really liked [that](https://github.com/lou/multi-select) plugin and tried to change JQuery code `.removeAttr('selected');` to JS code `.removeAttribute('selected');`. But I got an error. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I don't think that this can be useful, but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ca6Lu03s/2/) it is.

Comment: I've made an update, see: https://jsfiddle.net/jr7386fe/. I think the issue is that the multiSelect grabs the hml from the select and creates a UL. By altering the selected with JQuery, it might not alter the multiSelect. I would suggest adding a hidden input field to store selected id, which you can add/ remove by altering the "alert" event

Comment: have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/jr7386fe/2/ (I may have misunderstood the question)

Comment: Thank you so much. But, do you have any idea why it(number **1**) is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite understand what you meant by number 1. It might be easier if you create it in JSFiddle

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nebjkL1g/) it is. The issue is, you can't select the option again via `code` once you have deselected it with JQuery or by `clicking` on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218451/discussion-between-greg-and-sdeav).